# Integration Testing using Junit Patch and Delete end point work but get does not

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, mocking

Using junit5, Java21

```
@Tag("IntegrationTest")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ReasonsController.class)
public class ReasonsControllerIntegrationTest {

    private static final String ROOT_URL = "/company/00006400/extensions/requests/a1/reasons/";
    private static final String SPECIFIC_URL = "/company/00006400/extensions/requests/a1/reasons" +
        "/b2";
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ReasonsService reasonsService;

 @Test
    public void canReachUpdateReasonEndpoint() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.patch(
                SPECIFIC_URL)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(buildMockReason())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        Links links = new Links();
        links.setLink(ExtensionsLinkKeys.SELF, "url");
        ExtensionReasonDTO dto = new ExtensionReasonDTO();
        dto.setLinks(links);
        when(reasonsService.patchReason(any(ExtensionCreateReason.class), any(String.class), any(String.class)))
            .thenReturn(dto);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());
    }

    @Test
    public void canReachGetReasonsEndPoint() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/company/00006400/extensions/requests/a1/reasons/")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);


        ServiceResult<ListResponse<ExtensionReasonDTO>> expectedResult =
            ServiceResult.found(ListResponse.<ExtensionReasonDTO>builder()
                .withItems(Arrays.asList(new ExtensionReasonDTO()))
                .build());
        when(reasonsService.getReasons(anyString()))
            .thenReturn(expectedResult);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        assertEquals(200, result.getResponse().getStatus());
        assertEquals(mockGetResponse(), result.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }
```

I debugged and found out that library class DispatcherServlet.class has a method called doDispatch in this method we check Handlers and in case of get The controller class is not loaded but in case of patch it is loaded , How is it possible as both are within same class and configuration must be same

The library code line

```
processedRequest = this.checkMultipart(request);
multipartRequestParsed = processedRequest != request;
mappedHandler = this.getHandler(processedRequest);
```

For get call
HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]] and 5 interceptors

for Patch call
HandlerExecutionChain with [ReasonsController#patchReason(ExtensionCreateReason, String, String)] and 3 interceptors